# Does Clifford algebra depend on the topology of manifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

We know the greatest feature of Clifford algebra is coordinate-free. One can do vector operations without knowing the representation of vectors. And due to its very characteristc, Clifford or geometric algebra is believed to a reinterpretation of differential geometry suggested mainly by Hestenes and Doran. But as far as I know, many manifold-related theorem depends on the topology of the manifold such as connectedness, compactness, boundaryless or not. I want to know how Clifford algebra behave in different topologies?

Comment: I suspect this is something that the universal GA deftly avoids (just as it helps one avoid the arbitrariness of an embedding).  A vector manifold in the UGA may or may not have a boundary, certainly.  Being less well-versed in topology, I struggle to think about a vector manifold's connectedness or compactness, but I suspect these properties may be handled just through the choice of vectors that compose the vector manifold.

Comment: I wish I knew more about topologies in differential geometry. I would have expected that given a manifold and metric, that there is an associated topology. I would be a little surprised if there were many substantially different topologies compatible with the manifold and metric. Is this possible?